# Java wrapper classes. Casting

Tags: java, casting, wrapper

Is there a name for when you convert a primitive to an object using wrapper classes?
Im assuming this is also called casting correct?

Comment: In .NET, it is referred to as 'boxing' and converting an object to a value type is called 'unboxing.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called autoboxing. E.g.

```
Integer i = 5;   // i is an object but has a primitive value.
```

Comment: you're right. i learned it before i just forgot the name
thanks